# Confused about null-propagation

Tags: c#, null

I tried a few ways but could not convert the following statement to null-propagation.

Probably, I don't know how it works.

```cs
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (VGUILogger.Instance != null)
    {
        VGUILogger.Instance.HandleException(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: VGUILogger.Instance??.HandleException(ex);. Probably i'm not using the correct syntax. Sorry i'm very new to this.

Comment: if you search for "null propogation c#" you should find [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/csharp-the-new-and-improved-csharp-6-0)...

Comment: You should explain what you mean with "null-propagation".

Comment: Anyhow... an `Instance` method (probably a static generator for a singleton) returning null would be a bigger issue (and should actually throw)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
 VGUILogger.Instance?.HandleException(ex);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/csharp-the-new-and-improved-csharp-6-0